# Use checkboxGroupInput to render multiple uiOutputs

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any way to use `checkboxGroupInput` in a shiny app to render multiple uiOutputs:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$control1 <- renderUI({
    req(input$devs)
    if(input$devs %in% c("A")){
      selectInput("a", "control A", choices = c("a", "b"))
    }
  })

  output$control2 <- renderUI({
    req(input$devs)
    print(input$devs)
    if(input$devs %in% c("B")){
      selectInput("b", "controlB", choices = c("c", "d"))
    }
  }) 

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("devs", "Select controls", choices = c("A", "B")),
      uiOutput("control1"),
      uiOutput("control2")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have read some threads explaining how to render [multiple widgets](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/qQ8yICfvDu0) in the same uiOutput but to be clear I want to render multiple `uiOutput`s using one input. I know I could split the inputs into multiple `checkboxInputs` but I don't want to do that. The reason is I am passing my `checkboxGroupInput` selections as parameters into a [markdown report](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html) and would like to keep the selections with one ID (real app has lots of inputs).

Comment: What do you expect in your output??

Comment: I expect the outputs to be independent. So if input A is selected control1 shows, if B is selected control2 shows. And if both are selected then both show. Sorry I'll update question when I get back to laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a small change in your if statement.
`input$devs %in% "B"` will return `FALSE TRUE`, which will trigger the code within your if statement.

You can simply change it to:
`"B" %in% input$devs`.

Full code below:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$control1 <- renderUI({
    req(input$devs)
    if("A" %in% input$devs){
      selectInput("a", "control A", choices = c("a", "b"))
    }
  })

  output$control2 <- renderUI({
    req(input$devs)
    if("B" %in% input$devs){
      selectInput("b", "controlB", choices = c("c", "d"))
    }
  }) 

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("devs", "Select controls", choices = c("A", "B")),
      uiOutput("control1"),
      uiOutput("control2")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note that you could also aggregate the renderUI to sthg like:

```
choices - list()
choices[["A"]] <- c("a", "b")
choices[["B"]] <- c("c", "d")

observe({
   lapply(input$devs, function(letter){ 
      output[[paste0("control", letter) <- renderUI({
        if(letter %in% input$devs){
          selectInput(letter, paste0("control", letter), choices = choices[[letter]])
        }
      })
   }
})
```